# Twilio SMS Parsing using objective C

Tags: objective-c, parsing, sms, twilio

I need to integrate SMS Verification using Twilio url.

I have `ACCOUNT_SID`,`AUTH_TOKEN` and url but not able to parse using Objective C.

CODE:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config delegate:self delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"From='number'To=%@&Body=message %d to verify your mobile number.",txt_otp.text,[[self sms_verification_code]intValue]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/(SID)/SMS/Messages"]cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];


NSString *authStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SID:TOKEN"];
NSData *authData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [authData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]];
[request setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];


[[session dataTaskWithRequest:request
    completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];


            NSLog(@"SMS verification%@",responseDictionary);
        }
    }] resume];
```

Comment: Could you please post your code along with the error you're receiving? We would be able to help you much better :)

Comment: We don't recommend you make calls the the API directly from your application, as you'd need to embed your Account SID and Auth Token in the app, which someone could then decompile, steal and use your credit. It's better to build your own server which can make the API calls securely and return just the data your app needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have succeeded parsing using AFNetworking SDK.

```
NSString *kTwilioSID = @"sid";
            NSString *kTwilioSecret = @"token";
            NSString *kFromNumber = @"";
            NSString *kToNumber =@"";
            NSString *kMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"message %d",[[self sms_verification_code] intValue]];

            NSString *urlString = [NSString
                                   stringWithFormat:@"https://%@:%@@api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/%@/SMS/Messages/",
                                   kTwilioSID, kTwilioSecret,kTwilioSID];

            NSDictionary*
            dic=@{@"From":kFromNumber,@"To":kToNumber,@"Body":kMessage};


             AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
             manager.responseSerializer=[AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
             manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes=[NSSet setWithObject:@"application/xml"];
             [manager POST:urlString parameters:dic progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {


             NSLog(@"success %@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
             completion:nil];


             } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
             NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
             }];
```